# Resetting PRAM through Terminal

Tags: terminal, keyboard, high-sierra, reboot, nvram

For some reason, my Mac won't let me reset my PRAM in the usual way (by holding the relevant keys down when restarting), simply nothing happens when I try it and my Mac just boots up normally every time.

I'm suspecting this may be due to the fact I'm using a PC keyboard after I broke my Apple one a while back.

I read that I can reset my PRAM through Terminal with the following command:

```
sudo nvram boot-args=”-p -r”
```

But all I get is this error:

> nvram: Error setting variable - 'boot-args': (iokit/common) general error

I'm running High Sierra on a late 2009 iMac if that helps

Comment: I'd be more interested in why you think the NVRAM needs resetting. It's very rarely the 'fix' for anything.

Comment: Windows is the command key, so PC work for NVRAM resets when you hold the correct keys. Is that a workaround?

Comment: Additionally, [OS X Daily](http://osxdaily.com/2015/12/16/view-clear-nvram-mac-command-line-osx/) seems to think it should be `nvram -c` i cannot track down any ref to it in boot-args.

Answer (score 3):

According to an Apple Support page called "[Prepare your institution for iOS 10 and macOS Sierra](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206871)":

> ...you must use the nvram command to properly set boot-args NVRAM variable. Starting with macOS Sierra, you must be booted to the recovery partition to run this command.

But now you can clear the NVRAM with

```
sudo nvram -c
```

Then restart for the reset to take effect.

I also have a PC keyboard that doesn't seem able to reset the NVRAM on startup, but I think the real problem is that it's wireless. But this command is easier and more reliable anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) restriction rather than a keyboard issue. Read through the linked article to get an idea of what SIP is, and then try this:

- Ensure you have an up-to-date backup, in case of emergency.
- Power off your Map as normal.
- Hold down Cmd-R and press the Power button. Windows keyboard should be Win-R instead. Keep holding the keys down until the Apple logo appears, then release.
- Wait for macOS to boot into the recovery utilities window.
- From the Utilities menu, choose Terminal. Then: `csrutil disable`, then `exit`, then reboot into High Sierra as normal.

I'm not sure where you're getting `-p -r` as boot args to reset NVRAM, but `sudo nvram -c` should do the trick on High Sierra, as [Tetsujin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/85275/tetsujin) states [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/354627/resetting-pram-through-terminal#comment467690_354627).

When you're done, reboot into recovery mode once more, open Terminal and then re-enable SIP with `csrutil enable`, and reboot into High Sierra.